Go ozzo validation. check if a stuct field is in a slice
I have a struct like:
type Foo string
type Mystruct struct {
    currentFoo Foo
    foos []Foo
}

I want to validate that currentFoo is in foos. I am doing
func (s MyStruct) ValidateInput() error {

    return validation.ValidateStruct(&s, 
        validation.Field(&s.currentFoo, validation.In(s.foos).Error("currentfoo not in next foos")),
            )
}


But I am getting the error even when I know that currentFoo is in foos by printing logs.
Why does this not work?

As mentionned in validation.In documentation, you have to pass a list of values to the function. Something like that:
validation.ValidateStruct(&s,
    validation.Field(&s.currentFoo, validation.In(s.foos[0], s.foos[1],...).Error("currentfoo not in next foos")),
)

Or convert the foo slice to an interface slice:
    list := make([]interface{}, 0, len(s.foos))
    for _, foo := range s.foos {
        list = append(list, foo)
    }

    err := validation.ValidateStruct(&s,
        validation.Field(&s.currentFoo, validation.In(list...).Error("currentfoo not in next foos")),
    )

